# Testing MutationObserver with Jest

Tags: jestjs

I wrote a script with the main purpose of adding new elements to some table's cells.

The test is done with something like that:

```
document.body.innerHTML = `
<body>
    <div id="${containerID}">
        <table>
            <tr id="meta-1"><td> </td></tr>
            <tr id="meta-2"><td> </td></tr>
            <tr id="meta-3"><td> </td></tr>
            <tr id="no-meta-1"><td> </td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
`;

    const element = document.querySelector(`#${containerID}`);

    const subject = new WPMLCFInfoHelper(containerID);
    subject.addInfo();

    expect(mockWPMLCFInfoInit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
```

`mockWPMLCFInfoInit`, when called, is what tells me that the element has been added to the cell.

Part of the code is using MutationObserver to call again `mockWPMLCFInfoInit` when a new row is added to a table:

```
new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    mutations.map((mutation) => {
        mutation.addedNodes && Array.from(mutation.addedNodes).filter((node) => {
            console.log('New row added');
            return node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'tr';
        }).map((element) => WPMLCFInfoHelper.addInfo(element))
    });
}).observe(metasTable, {
    subtree:   true,
    childList: true
});
```

`WPMLCFInfoHelper.addInfo` is the real version of `mockWPMLCFInfoInit` (which is a mocked method, of course).

From the above test, if add something like that...

```
const table = element.querySelector(`table`);
var row = table.insertRow(0);
```

`console.log('New row added');` never gets called. 
To be sure, I've also tried adding the required cells in the new row.

Of course, a manual test is telling me that the code works.

Searching around, my understanding is that MutationObserver is not supported and [there is no plan to support it](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/580).

Fair enough, but in this case, how can I test this part of my code? Except manually, that is :)

Comment: You'll need to create a mock implementation of `MutationObserver` that behaves how you need it to.

Comment: @AlexRobertson Mocking would not a problem for an imported module, but I have no idea of how to mock something defined as `MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;` which is how I've learned to deal with them.

Answer (score 36):

I know I'm late to the party here, but in my jest setup file, I simply added the following mock `MutationObserver` class.

```
global.MutationObserver = class {
    constructor(callback) {}
    disconnect() {}
    observe(element, initObject) {}
};
```

This obviously won't allow you to test that the observer does what you want, but will allow the rest of your code's tests to run which is the path to a working solution.

Comment: Just remember, this WILL NOT test the mutation observer's stuff. I still have not found a good solution to that so the mutation observer's part in my code is still scary.

Comment: You can use Jest mock functions to mock `MutationObserver`. This allows you to test instances of it in your code. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60974039/1443040) for an example.

Comment: For some reason that won't work for me. I have to define it in the test file, which is really a pain.

Answer (score 14):

I think a fair portion of the solution is just a mindset shift. Unit tests shouldn't determine whether `MutationObserver` is working properly. Assume that it is, and mock the pieces of it that your code leverages.

Simply extract your callback function so it can be tested independently; then, mock `MutationObserver` (as in [samuraiseoul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50626200/1443040)) to prevent errors. Pass a mocked [MutationRecord](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) list to your callback and test that the outcome is expected.

That said, using Jest mock functions to mock `MutationObserver` and its `observe()` and `disconnect()` methods would at least allow you to check the number of `MutationObserver` instances that have been created and whether the methods have been called at expected times.

```js
const mutationObserverMock = jest.fn(function MutationObserver(callback) {
    this.observe = jest.fn();
    this.disconnect = jest.fn();
    // Optionally add a trigger() method to manually trigger a change
    this.trigger = (mockedMutationsList) => {
        callback(mockedMutationsList, this);
    };
});
global.MutationObserver = mutationObserverMock;

it('your test case', () => {
    // after new MutationObserver() is called in your code
    expect(mutationObserverMock.mock.instances).toBe(1);

    const [observerInstance] = mutationObserverMock.mock.instances;
    expect(observerInstance.observe).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want! Except in my setup its doesn't have any effect. I'm getting this error "[BootstrapVue warn]: observeDom: Requires MutationObserver support." Doing vue unit testing using jest, bootstrapVue, vue-test-utils. Any further hints would be awesome.

Comment: @rodhoward While I can't speak to what might be happening with BootstrapVue, my example was used in a vue-cli project using vue-test-utils. We were using MutationObserver manually in our own code, though. BootstrapVue has a `hasMutationObserverSupport` check in [src/utils/env.js](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/3c7a3c0378494d6debc4ad7a82902f40dbcc3bfd/src/utils/env.js#L12). My best guess is that it has something to do with it being in `node_modules`, and how jest handles that?

Answer (score 10):

The problem is actually appears because of JSDom doesn't support `MutationObserver`, so you have to provide an appropriate *polyfill*.

Little tricky thought may not the best solution (let's use library intend for compatibility with IE9-10).

- you can take opensource project like this one https://github.com/webmodules/mutation-observer which represents similar logic
- import to your test file and make global

Step 1 (install this library to devDependencies)

```
npm install --save-dev mutation-observer
```

Step 2 (Import and make global)

```
import MutationObserver from 'mutation-observer'
global.MutationObserver = MutationObserver 

test('your test case', () => { 
   ...
})
```

Comment: There is zero need for a 3rd-party package. You can simply mock it yourself.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `mutationobserver-shim`.

Add this in setup.js

```js
import "mutationobserver-shim"
```

and install

```
npm i -D mutationobserver-shim
```

Comment: There is zero need for a 3rd-party package. You can simply mock it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Since it's not mentioned here: jsdom has supported MutationObserver for a while now.

Here's the PR implementing it https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/pull/2398

Comment: for testing I add a 1ms timeout to wait for the mutation observer to kick in:
```
const timeout = (ms) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};
await timeout(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a typescript rewrite of Matt's answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60974039/400861).

```js
// Test setup
const mutationObserverMock = jest
  .fn<MutationObserver, [MutationCallback]>()
  .mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      observe: jest.fn(),
      disconnect: jest.fn(),
      takeRecords: jest.fn(),
    };
  });
global.MutationObserver = mutationObserverMock;

// Usage
new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log("lol");
}).observe(document, {});

// Test
const observerCb = mutationObserverMock.mock.calls[0][0];
observerCb([], mutationObserverMock.mock.instances[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had a similar problem, where I wanted to assert on something that should be set by MutationObserver and I think I found fairly simple solution.

I made my test method `async` and added `await new Promise(process.nextTick);` just before my assertion. It puts the new promise at the end on microtask queue and holds the test execution until it is resolved. This allows for the MutationObserver callback, which was put on the microtask queue before our promise, to be executed and make changes that we expect.

So in general the test should look somewhat like this:

```js
it('my test', async () => {
    somethingThatTriggersMutationObserver();
    await new Promise(process.nextTick);
    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition for TypeScript users:

declare the module with adding a file called: mutation-observer.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/mutation-observer" />
declare module "mutation-observer";
```

Then in your jest file.

```
import MutationObserver from 'mutation-observer'
(global as any).MutationObserver = MutationObserver
```

Answer (score 0):

**very late** to the party but here is how I mocked `MutationObserver` using sinon.

```
    sinon.stub(global, 'MutationObserver').callsFake(() =>
    {
        return new class
        {
            constructor(callback) { }
            disconnect() { }
            observe(element, initObject) { }
        }
    });
```