# ts-jest fails to run a tsx test file because of "Import" from a module's js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to use `ts-jest` to run a tsx test file `form.spec.tsx`.

The `form.spec.tsx` imports `React Quill` editor and some of the plugins.

How can I bypass `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error coming from a plugin called [quill-mention](https://github.com/afconsult/quill-mention) that import `Quill`? This module is involved in `form.spec.tsx`.

I have added `["<rootDir>/node_modules/"]` to the transformIgnorePatterns field in jest configuration, but this problem still exists from [/node_modules/quill-mention/src/quill.mention.js](https://github.com/afconsult/quill-mention/blob/master/src/quill.mention.js)

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /home/web/node_modules/quill-mention/src/quill.mention.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import Quill from 'quill';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      1 | import React from "react"
    > 2 | import "quill-mention";
        | ^
```

form.spec.tsx:

```
import {render, RenderResult, waitForElement} from "react-testing-library";
import ReactQuill, {Quill} from 'react-quill';
import "quill-mention";

const renderResult = render(
        <ReactQuill
            modules={
             {
                mention: {
                   allowedChars: /^[A-Za-z\sÅÄÖåäö]*$/,
                   mentionDenotationChars: ["@", "#"],
                },
            }
        />
);
```

package.json

```
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.jest.json"
      },
      "window": {}
    },
    "testRegex": "(/watch/web/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsxxxx?|tsx?)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      ".+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/FileMock.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ]
  }
```

tsconfig.jest.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "types": ["jest","reflect-metadata"],
    "inlineSources":true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Someone says `allowJs: true` could fix it but it doesn't work. All of my tests failed saying `JavaScript heap out of memory`.

Comment: can you include your `tsconfig.jest.json` content in your question?

Comment: @CarlosCrespo, the tsconfig.jest.json is basically the same as tsconfig.json. Please check the updated thread.

Comment: I don't see a jest config. It should look something like [this](https://github.com/indiana-department-of-transportation/react-ctx-store/blob/master/jest.config.js).

Comment: @JaredSmith the jest config is in package.json

Comment: can you maybe try removing the `<rootDir>/` from `transformIgnorePatterns`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that Jest is ***not*** transforming that file. And in plain JS, `import` is not valid. You need to configure Jest so it will transform that file.

First, change the `transform` to also process files with extensions `js` or `jsx` (in addition to `ts` files:)

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|js)x?$": "ts-jest"
  },
```

Next you need to whitelist the directory, so Jest does transform it. This skips transforming all files in `node_modules` *except* the `quill-mention` dir.

```
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(quill-mention)/)"
    ]
```

This should get past the problems with `quill-mention`. And it should now fail with `ReferenceError: MutationObserver is not defined`, which is a different issue, having to do with Jest's JSDom environment it uses. You can read about how to fix that here:

[Testing MutationObserver with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809753/testing-mutationobserver-with-jest)

You may also want to consider moving to `babel-jest` + `@babel/preset-typescript` instead of using `ts-jest`.

Comment: I've used ts-jest without a transform setting, but `srcDir` and `outDir` were set, so no `.js` sidecar files were generated. This might be another solution.

Comment: "And in plain JS, import is not valid." Uh, what? es6 modules are a thing

Comment: @MingweiSamuel only experimental support when I wrote this answer. https://thecodebarbarian.com/nodejs-12-imports. And you can read more about the Jest transform option and "plain JS" here. https://jestjs.io/docs/next/code-transformation