# react typescript testing TypeError: MutationObserver is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I created a React app with `create-react` last week.

I have a simple form that displays a message when I click submit.

I would like to test it, this is the test i created **SampleForm.test.tsx**:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import SampleForm from "./SampleForm";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"


test("renders submits form", async () => {
    const str = "THIS DIDNT DO ANYTHING";
    const { container, getByText, findByText } = render(<SampleForm />);

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText("Submit"));

    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText(str)))
});
```

I'm getting an error at `waitFor`

> TypeError: MutationObserver is not a constructor

**stack trace:**

```
at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:38:22
      at waitFor (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:31:10)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:70:54
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:51:22
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:60:24
      at batchedUpdates$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21856:12)
      at act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:929:14)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:59:20
      at asyncAct (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:38:14)
      at Object.asyncWrapper (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:50:35)
      at waitForWrapper (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:70:35)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/SampleForm.test.tsx:18:11)
```

I have tried several different alterations of the style and text querying. Derived off of the samples [here](https://testing-library.com/)

[This is the straight example i'm trying to get to work](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro)

I'm hesitant about adding shims and gyrations because according to the example I shouldn't have to do any of that.  I'd like to understand why that example isn't working.

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "intact",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rjsf/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.0.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.5",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "msal": "^1.2.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-aad-msal": "^2.3.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^13.11.0",
    "@types/rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.8.1"
  }
}
```

edits: 04-05-2020

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing MutationObserver with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809753/testing-mutationobserver-with-jest)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Are you running latest CRA? If so then this issue https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8362 might be what you're experiencing. That's solvable by installing https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen, e.g. `$ yarn add -D jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen` and editing your test script:

```
 ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
-   "test": "react-scripts test --env=dom"
+   "test": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen"
    ...
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen": "^1.0.3",
    ...
  },
  ...
```

Essentially you will tell your jest to use jsdom v16 instead of v15(default for Jest v25).

Comment: when using Jetbrain webstorm's test profiles I was finding it a pain to add --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen to every single new test profile.  So an alternative is to put 

```/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom-sixteen
 */```

at the top of the test file

Comment: @Keegan82 Your answer helped a lot. It pointed me to the test file that already had `@jest-environment jsdom` which was obviously overwriting the package.json setting in the answer above.

Comment: @Keegan82 You should expand that into an answer. (Also, related link: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/731#issuecomment-667632723)

Answer (score 6):

I also faced the same issue.

Before trying the accepted answer, I updated `react-scripts` to version `4.0.1`.

That solved the issue, because `react-scripts 4.0.1` uses Jest `26.6.x`.

Therefore, try upgrading `react-scripts` first.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I was running a very old version of node.js on Windows.  When I updated to node version **12.16.3**, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This is my scene:

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'enzyme',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-enzyme'],
  setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    enzymeAdapter: 'react16',
  },
};
```

`package.json`:

```json
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
"jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
"ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
"typescript": "^4.1.2"

"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

Got error:

```
TypeError: MutationObserver is not a constructor

       9 |     const { getByTestId } = render(<Login />);
      10 |     expect(getByTestId('getUrl').getAttribute('href')).toEqual('');
    > 11 |     const url = await waitFor(() => getByTestId('getUrl'));
```

But when I changed the `testEnvironment` configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  // testEnvironment: 'enzyme',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-enzyme'],
  setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    enzymeAdapter: 'react16',
  },
};
```

The test passes:

```
 PASS  examples/65336283/LoginLink.test.tsx
  65336283
    ✓ should display loginurl (23 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3 s, estimated 4 s
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was updating from an old version of jest and had to make sure to include the appropriate testing environment in `package.json` as none was set:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "jest --env=jsdom"
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```