# React testing: "TypeError: MutationObserver is not a constructor"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs, mutation-observers

### The Problem

I'm trying to test a new release of an internal component library, which recently upgraded some dependencies and now uses [Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jest_(JavaScript_framework)) 26 internally. That library also exports some testing helpers.

In another codebase that utilizes the aforementioned component library, I'm getting the following when running certain unit tests:

```
TypeError: MutationObserver is not a constructor

    at /<path_to_repo>/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:78:18
```

This may or may not be related to the fact that the testing helpers exported by the component library relied on Jest 26. (It's hard to tell if these helpers are being used -- we've got some very big "unit" tests.)

Relevant package versions (in the consuming codebase):

- react-scripts 3.4.4
- Jest 24.9.0
- testing-library/dom 7.26.3
- testing-library/jest-dom 5.10.0
- testing-library/react ^10.0.0

Running `yarn list jsdom` yields the following:

```
├─ jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen@1.0.1
│  └─ jsdom@14.1.0
├─ jest-environment-jsdom@24.9.0
│  └─ jsdom@11.12.0
└─ jsdom@16.4.0
```

I know that upgrading `react-scripts` and Jest would likely fix this issue, but I'm trying to find a way that doesn't involve that. (We ideally don't want this to be a prerequisite for upgrading to our new component library version.)

### Attempted Solutions

#### Forcing a Newer `jsdom`

First I tried adding

```json
"resolutions": {
  "jsdom": "^14.0.0"
},
```

to my `package.json`. This did make `yarn list jsdom` output only `jsdom@14.1.0`, but I still got the same `TypeError`. Resolving to `^15.0.0` resulted in the same error, and resolving to `^16.0.0` gave me the following error:

```
TypeError: this.dom.runVMScript is not a function

  at JSDOMEnvironment.runScript (node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js:187:23)
```

#### Using `jest-environment-jsdom-*`

I tried following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61039444/500117) by installing `jest-environment-jsom-sixteen`. Altering my `test` script in `package.json` and running `yarn test --showConfig` yields a bunch of info including the following line:

```json
"testEnvironment": "/<path_to_repo>/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen/lib/index.js",
```

If I add a `console.log(navigator.userAgent)` to my test, I also get

```
Mozilla/5.0 (darwin) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) jsdom/16.4.0
```

However, I still get the same `TypeError: MutationObserver is not a constructor`.

I also tried `jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen` and `jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen`, and tried while forcing `jsdom` to `^14.0.0`. Same result.

#### Using `mutationobserver-shim`

I ran `yarn add -D mutationobserver-shim` and imported it (with `import 'mutationobserver-shim'`) in my `jestSetup.ts` (which is what `globalSetup` in my Jest configuration points to), but that resulted in the following error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
  at Object.<anonymous> (/<path_to_repo>/node_modules/mutationobserver-shim/dist/mutationobserver.min.js:12:1)
```

Adding the import instead to my test file yielded the same `TypeError` as above, and adding a `console.log(global.MutationObserver)` to my test file yielded `undefined`.

### A Not-So-Great Solution

After a lot of trial and error, I discovered that if I 1) have `jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen` installed and tell Jest to use it and 2) add `import 'mutationobserver-shim'` *in my test file*, and the tests will pass. However, if I put add the import to my Jest `globalSetup` file, it doesn't work. I get the same `ReferenceError: window is not defined` error as before.

### My Question

How can I get rid of both errors without requiring users of our component library to add an import statement to all of their test files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A polyfill should be applied in `setupFilesAfterEnv`, because this is where the [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) environment is instantiated and [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) becomes available. `window` isn't supposed to be available in `globalSetup` because it doesn't run in a test scope.

In case this is an unejected create-react-app project, the setup file that corresponds to `setupFilesAfterEnv` is `src/setupTests.ts` (`src/setupTests.js`).

That the newer `jsdom` version causes an error means it's incompatible with the old Jest version (24). They should be ejected and upgraded, or newer CRA (`react-scripts@4`) with Jest 26 support has to be used.

Comment: This did get rid of the `ReferenceError: window is not defined`, but now I'm back to the other problem where `window.MutationObserver` is not preserved from `src/setupTests.ts` to my actual test. (I can add `console.log` statements in both locations and see that it's defined in the former but not in the latter.)

Comment: Which of described cases do you mean by 'back'?  I'm not sure how it's possible.`window.MutationObserver` should be available in a test too because setupTests and a test run in the same scope, unless you did something in test file that could remove it like accidentally assigning it. Try to make it read-only in setupTests after you confirmed it's available there, `Object.defineProperty(window, 'MutationObserver', { writable: false, configurable: false, value: MutationObserver })`. Make sure you don't do anything odd with your environment like `jest-environment-jsdom-*` that you mentioned

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I just found this later in that file:
`Object.defineProperty(window, 'MutationObserver', { value: undefined });` That'll do it! Removing it fixed the issue, and I don't even need the shim. Thank you for pointing me to `src/setupTests.ts`!