# waitFor not working React Testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

i am trying for a delete icon to appear before executing rest of the test case issue is happening for waitFor from react testing library

my imports

```
import { render, screen, waitFor, fireEvent } from '../../../TestMocks/CustomRender';
import DraftPage from '../DraftPage';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React from 'react';
```

draftpage - showing a small part of actual code

```
{
loader ?
<Grid data-testid="full page loader">
    <CircularProgress />
</Grid>
:
<Grid>
   <IconButton
      disabled={item.notSynced}>
      <DeleteIcon data-testid="draft delete icon" onClick={()=>{console.log('btn click')}} />
   </IconButton>
</Grid>
}
```

draftpage.test.js

```
it("delete a card number reduce", async () => {
    render(<DraftPage />);
    const loader = screen.getAllByTestId("full page loader")
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId("draft delete icon")).toBeInTheDocument())
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("draft delete icon"));
    expect(screen.getByText("draft delete dialog")).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

error:

```
 FAIL  src/Components/Draft/__Test__/DraftPage.test.js (11.746s)
  √ renders draft page (193ms)
  × delete a card number reduce (55ms)

  ● delete a card number reduce

    TypeError: MutationObserver is not a constructor

      75 |     const loader = screen.getAllByTestId("full page loader")
      76 |     console.log(loader)
    > 77 |     await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId("draft delete icon")).toBeInTheDocument())
         |           ^
      78 |     fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("draft delete icon"));
      79 |     expect(screen.getByText("draft delete dialog")).toBeInTheDocument();
      80 | })

      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:106:18
      at waitFor (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:39:10)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:188:54
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:59:22
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:63:24
      at batchedUpdates$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21856:12)
      at act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:929:14)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:62:20
      at asyncAct (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:40:14)
      at Object.asyncWrapper (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:58:35)
      at waitForWrapper (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:188:35)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Components/Draft/__Test__/DraftPage.test.js:77:11)
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61039444/532314

Comment: No, tried most of the upgrades

Answer (score 0):

Try running with `--env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen` ([source](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/477#issuecomment-598606649)).

Comment: no did not work.