# Mutation observer is not a constructor (Jest)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, react-testing-library

I am trying to use Jest with a new CRA project, but I am facing a problem when trying to use the `findByText` function. I installed:

```
yarn add -D jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen
```

And run my tests with `react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen`. It works fine if I do this solution that I encountered while reading these issues here:

- https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/477
- https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/662
- https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/731

However I am also using the Jest plugin from VS code and tests do not pass with it. I have tried to do this in my `jest.config.js` as suggested [in the docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#jest-24-or-lower-and-defaults):

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen',
};
```

But it still does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

[Testing MutationObserver with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809753/testing-mutationobserver-with-jest):
Try this, it worked for me, on a similar error:

1. `npm i -D mutationobserver-shim`
2. `import "mutationobserver-shim";` in setupTests.js

Comment: The above worked for me using React TS and Vite